# Is it possible to select against a post's parent's fields with WP_Query?

Tags: wp-query, get-posts, sql, revisions

I'd like to query post revisions using `WP_Query` for display on an admin page, and I want to include pagination parameters.

I have two constraints:

1. I would like to only retrieve revisions for *published* posts, i.e. revisions whose parent - the post ID for which is given in the `post_parent` field - contains `publish` in its `post_status` field.
2. I would like to ignore the revision autogenerated when a post is published, i.e. the revision whose `post_date` matches that of the parent.

Normally I would simply filter these revisions out after getting the array of posts, but I want to display these elements in an admin list table with pagination so I'd like to use `WP_Query`'s support for that.

In SQL, I would use an INNER JOIN like this to grab the parent posts:

```
SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->posts} AS posts
INNER JOIN {$wpdb->posts} AS parent_posts
ON posts.post_parent = parent_posts.ID
WHERE posts.post_type = 'revision'
AND parent_posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND posts.post_date <> parent_posts.post_date
```

Is this possible to do this using `WP_Query`?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `posts_join` and `posts_where` filters to modify *JOIN* and *WHERE* clauses.

```
add_filter( 'posts_join' , 'se333659_posts_join', 20, 2 );
add_filter( 'posts_where' , 'se333659_posts_where', 20, 2 );

function se333659_posts_join( $join, $query )
{
    global $wpdb;

    if ( isset($query->query_vars['_rev_of_publ']) &&
        $query->query_vars['_rev_of_publ'] == '1' )
    {
        $join .= " LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} AS rev_p ON ({$wpdb->posts}.post_parent = rev_p.ID) ";
    }
    return $join;
}

function se333659_posts_where( $where, $query )
{
    global $wpdb;

    if ( isset($query->query_vars['_rev_of_publ']) &&
        $query->query_vars['_rev_of_publ'] == '1' )
    {
        $where .= ' AND rev_p.post_status = \'publish\' AND '.$wpdb->posts.'.post_date <> rev_p.post_date ';
    }
    return $where;
}
```

### How to use:

Changes in the query will be made after passing the `_rev_of_publ` parameter (name can be changed) to `WP_Query`.

```
$args = [
    'post_type'     => 'revision',
    'post_status'   => 'any',     // default value is 'publish'
    '_rev_of_publ'  => 1,
];
$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

[Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Usage) you will find more information about using `WP_Query`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. I did consider this approach, but I figure it's equally if not more complex than a raw SQL query as I put in the original post - indeed, your solution still involves appending SQL to the query. I had hoped there was a way to do this sort of join with `WP_Query` itself to avoid all of the complaints from `WPCS` in my plugin about direct database interactions.

Comment: @Sean The filters mentioned above are used to expand `WP_Query` with custom joins and conditions. I'm afraid there is no other way than raw SQL or filters. Anyway, I do not know him. Conditions added to `where` don't have to be hard coded, they also can be passed as `WP_Query` parameter like `_rev_of_publ`.